# Org.springframework.HttpClientErrorException$unauthorized : 401 [no body]

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have to create a java api (micro apps using spring boot) for calling rest service. In postman or soapUi, i can able to get the response (either failure or success response). But when i hit that Rest Service in java APi, i was getting this below mentioned error, i am using exchange method to call this rest service and also using same headers as used in postman and service request mapped correctly.

org.springframework.HttpClientErrorException$unauthorised : 401 [no body]

I believe, if any Authorization is required in headers then i should get the same error in postman also, correct me if i am wrong. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: have you add spring security in your Springboot REST API?

Comment: Yes i did add spring security.

Comment: I can get the response from postman, but i tried the same header and request everything in java api, i get the error 401 unauthorised no body

Comment: post your spring security config please